# HTML Help-Not sure of the answer I Chose 4

Tags: html

Suppose you have an image that is 1500 × 1500 CSS pixels to be displayed on your web page, but you expect that all of your users will be using a mobile device whose width and height do not exceed the equivalent of 500 CSS pixels.  What is the best practice?

1. Keep the original image and set the width and height attributes to 500 or less in the HTML.
2. Display the image as is, setting the width and height attributes to 1500 or less in the HTML.
3. Keep the original image and set the width and height attributes to 500px or less in the CSS.
4. Resize the image to 500 X 500 CSS pixels or smaller in a program such as Photoshop.

Comment: I’d simply resize it and offer it as a second alternative, detect what size the window has, display the alternative that is most appropriate, style the picture with `width:100%;` (or similar) to fit window size. That’s best for people with low bandwidth.

Comment: There are pros and cons to all the techniques (and you haven't event touched on the `<picture>` element and the issue of ultra high resolution screens (i.e. what Apple call "retina"). It should be noted that you can't use a graphics editor to resize an image to a certain number of CSS pixels because the size of a CSS pixel varies depending on the user's device

Comment: "not sure of the answer" - is this a homework / test question?